# GUI in Qt OR GUI in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, qt4

Embedded Application (GUI) written in QT and communicating (Via IPC, SPI some other mechanism) with an Android based application (the primary application). Would like to know 
1. The overall pros and cons of such design 
2. Re usability of the GUI (would it be better to write your GUI on Android?)
3. Consider the two apps will be running on different machines (Linux and windows), how feasible it would be for them to communicate.

What is the best way to do this sort of design. I am new(in QT and Android) and do not know of the other preferred practice.

Any info would be useful.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use the GUI toolkit that fits the operating system. Android's GUI for programs running on Android, QT for programs running on Linux or Windows.

Comment: Agree with you, But can you use an app written on Android with some other applications written on different OS (say Linux, windows) and not on Android. My point is about the re usability of any app written on Android.

Comment: Even though it is possible (to run Android apps e.g. on Windows or Ubuntu), it hardly makes sense IMO, except for testing or similar purposes. Regarding communication, I'd use the network APIs, connecting on loopback, unless performance prohibits that. This way it's trivially easy to switch to a distributed setup.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [Android Lighthouse](http://code.google.com/p/android-lighthouse/wiki/Compile), which is a Qt port for Android.